# Can't pickle objects with recursive references

Tags: python, recursion, pickle

I want to create a set of these objects and pickle/unpickle them. However, if there is a recursive reference such as:

```
mdp1 = MDP(0, (0,1))
mdp2 = MDP(0, (0,2))
mdp1.adj = frozenset({mdp2})
mdp2.adj = frozenset({mdp1})
mdps = {mdp1, mdp2}
p_on = open("test.pickle", "wb")
pickle.dump(mdps, p_on)
p_on.close()

p_off = open("test.pickle", "rb")
emp = pickle.load(p_off)
print(emp)
```

In this case `mdp1.adj` contains `mdp2` and `mdp2` contains `mdp1`.

As a minimal reproducible example:

```
import pickle


    class MDP(object):
        def __init__(self, level, state_var):
            self.state_var = state_var
            self.level = level
            self.adj = frozenset()
            self.mer = frozenset()
            ...

        def __repr__(self):
           return "level {} var {} mer {}".format(self.level, self.state_var, self.mer)
    
        def __eq__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, MDP):
                return (self.level == other.level and self.state_var == other.state_var and self.mer==other.mer)
            else:
                return False
    
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self.__repr__())
    
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return self.state_var < other.state_var

    def main():
        mdp1 = MDP(0, (0,1))
        mdp2 = MDP(0, (0,2))
        mdp1.adj = frozenset({mdp2})
        mdp2.adj = frozenset({mdp1})
        mdps = {mdp1, mdp2}
        p_on = open("test.pickle", "wb")
        pickle.dump(mdps, p_on)
        p_on.close()

        p_off = open("test.pickle", "rb")
        emp = pickle.load(p_off)
        print(emp)

    main()
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../test.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "../test.py", line 39, in main
    emp = pickle.load(p_off)
  File "../test.py", line 22, in __hash__
    return hash(self.__repr__())
  File "../test.py", line 13, in __repr__
    return "level {} var {} mer {}".format(self.level, self.state_var, self.mer)
AttributeError: 'MDP' object has no attribute 'level'
```

Comment: You've got some bug somewhere in some code you haven't shown us. We can't say much more than that without a [mcve].

Comment: I can see some problems in what you've shown us - for example, these objects are mutable in ways that affect equality, so they almost certainly shouldn't be hashable, and the fact that they're hashable suggests you may have some serious design issues - but we don't have enough information to diagnose the AttributeError.

Comment: The stack trace suggests that the actual code you're running is completely different from the (fragments of a) class definition you've shown us.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I've included a minimal reproducible example and the stack trace. Perhaps changing `mer` to a frozen set will make it hashable and fix my problem.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I've tried changing my implementation to use frozen sets, but I am getting the same error!

Comment: The sets being mutable isn't the problem. The problem is that *your* `MDP` objects are mutable and hashable.

Comment: Also, please make sure you post the stack trace that goes with whatever version of the code you have posted. Don't let the question's code and error message go out of sync.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica  Okay, I've updated the stack trace. It's my understand that all objects in python are mutable, I can't give a class an immutable `int` property for example. So what would you suggest in this case?

Comment: There's a difference between "physically" and logically immutable. You (mostly) can't *stop* code from mutating your objects, but you can document that they shouldn't be mutated, treat them as mutable, and make sure the design doesn't require mutating them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228442/discussion-between-ricky-avina-and-user2357112-supports-monica).

Comment: \*treat them as *immutable*. can't edit the comment any more, since it's over 5 minutes old.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same question [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) helped explain that during the unpickling process: due to the circular references, some objects are going to have to see other objects in uninitialized or partially-initialized states during the unpickling process, and pickle has no idea what cases that is or isn't safe for.
It ends up trying to add an MDP instance to an adj set before setting level.

This happens because of the way I've defined hash functions and equality in my class. Deleting those custom definitions and letting python handle equality and hashing fixed my problem. Pickle is capable of serializing objects with circular references: https://pymotw.com/2/pickle/#circular-references